# Ubuntu problems with repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I am having some problems with my repositories. It happened suddenly without I did anything and I cant understand why.
I am running ubuntu 19.10.
I tried many things like resetting my source.list or modifying the main server in the software-gtk application. WHen I change the server, I get a "refresh softwares" screen that leads to a ubuntu error. Afterwards, I cant access the software-gtk anymore.
I cannot install anything anymore with the command apt-get install packagename.
If I use aptitude and make an update:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE2p7.png)

Below you will find the result of sudo apt update (the end because otherwise it is too long):

```
Ign:148 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:149 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/multiverse all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:150 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/restricted Sources
Ign:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/multiverse Sources
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main Sources
Ign:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main all Packages
Ign:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main Translation-en
Ign:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And here is my source.list file:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb [trusted=yes] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-security main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
```

I do not know what to do as I would like to avoid reinstalling the system... Any idea of what is happening?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are running an EoL release. This is expected.

Comment: What is an EoL release and how to change it without formatting?

Comment: EoL = End of Life. You can't "change it". You need a fresh install.

Comment: I should go to ubuntu 20 ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases - Standard releases are only supported 9 months and require an upgrade every 6-9 months. LTS releases are supported for 3-5 years.

Comment: you should go to 20.10 or 20.04 - I'd recommend 20.04 as it'll be supported much longer as it's a LTS release (LongTermSupport) - see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases - see how to upgrade to 20.04 here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try your solutions as I was not aware of this!

Comment: The update will break my setup?

Comment: Yes it will break "your setup" whatever it is. It will be a fresh install.

Comment: a distro-upgarde is not a fresh install I think - but issues could arrive when upgrading from19.10 to 20.04 - setup will be kept as much as possible - the 20.04 release notes lists some known issues - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes explains some of the main changes of the new ubuntu version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 19.10 is End Of Life - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/

It's recommended to upgrade to 20.04 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades

For ubuntu desktops the process is as follows

```
You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

    Run the update-manager application;

    In Update Manager, click the Settings... button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.

    Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.
    Confirm the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" option is set to "For any new version" if you are using 19.10 or to "For long-term support versions" if you are using 18.04 LTS. If it is not set properly modify it the appropriate option.
    Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.

    In Update Manager, click the Check button to check for new updates.

    If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, then exit.

    In a terminal run update-manager -c -d. 

    Follow the on-screen instructions.
```

This site shows two possible processes : via software apps or via terminal commands in more detail : https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-19-10-to-ubuntu-20-04